# $type in JSON request doesn't work in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

It's in .net core WebAPI, it doesn't read $type in the following code

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost("Order")]
public string Order([FromBody] OrderRequest rq)
{
    var a = new OrderRequest 
    {
        Version = "12",
        Typea = new MsgType
        {
            A = new MsgTypeA
            {
                Item = new MsgSubTypeA
                {
                    SubA = "TEST"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto//.All
    });
}
```

Request is

```
{
   "Typea":    {
      "A": {"Item":       {
         "$type": "Services.WebReference.MsgSubTypeA, Services.WebReference",
         "SubA":"TEST"
         }
      }}
   }
}
```

It just cannot read the $type, and cannot convert "Item" to correct type, but to its base class. However, the response generated per JsonConvert.SerializeObject shows the same JSON.

What's wrong?

Comment: The request object is in rq..Where do you use that in the controller?

Comment: @MarcusH sorry.. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now resolved

```
public string Order([FromBody] JObject rq)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRequest>(rq.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    });
```

Another way could be better:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    })
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, but in my case I had two different projects, because of this the namespace was different, so I solved it using replace to change the wrong namespace in Json object.